# Kotlin/PostgreSQL query returning only last row when expected all rows with selected id

Tags: postgresql, kotlin

I am working for the first time with Kotlin and functional programming. I have a piece of code where I expected that the query would return all the rows from the DB where the **id** matches the selected **id**. In my case I have a **consigment** table where one of the columns is **order_id**. I am trying to get all rows with specific **order_id** like this:

```
val consignmentIdsV = orderIdsV.validFlatMap { validateMoveOrder(ctx, it.second) }.named("consignmentId")
```

Where **validateMoveOrder** looks like this:

```
private fun validateMoveOrder(ctx: Ctx, orderIds: List<Long>): Validated<Err, List<Long>> =
    fetchRows(ctx, "select c.id, c.state, c.slot_id from consignment c where order_id = any(:orderIds)", mapOf("orderIds" to orderIds))
        .map {
          return if (consignmentCanBeMoved.contains(ConsignmentState.byName(it["state"] as String)) && it["slotId"] == null)
            listOf(it["id"].toString().toLong()).valid()
          else
            SErr(GlowErrs.ORDER_CANNOT_BE_MOVED, "Order ${it["id"]} cannot be moved").invalid()
        }.joinInvalid()
```

But, this is currently not working. In my case when I have few consigments (3 to be more specific) with the same order_id, I get only the last row as a result. Why am I not getting all 3 rows as expected?

Comment: What sql framework is this?

Comment: @JensV it is postgresql

Comment: I mean where do the `fetchRows` and `joinInvalid()` functions come from. Did you implement those yourself? It's hard to reason about what exactly is happening without knowing that

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're returning a list with only one item if your condition is met. You need to collect all items before returning the list.
My pseudo code would look a little different as I would use `filter()` instead of `map()`:

```
return fetchRows(...)
.filter(...)
.toList()
```